# Docker-compose trouble to mount local volume

Tags: php, apache, symfony, docker, docker-compose

I've tried to setup a little apache to test my php stuff.
But the server won't let me access my files. (error 403)

I've mounted my stuff with

```
volumes:
- /home/<user>/Workspace/Symfony/<my_project>:/var/www/html:rw
```

do I have to grant any permissions or something?
sry I'm not that familiar with docker... :-/

hope someone can help me :)

greets,
larusso

Comment: What are the current permissions on the files ( I tend to have 664 on files )

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache HTTPD documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions) permissions should be **640** for files and **750** for directories.

Also for playing locally `chmod 700 /var/www/html` will work.